# unable to install singularity in Centos or Ubuntu

Tags: singularity-container

I need help on how to install singularity in Centos or Ubuntu successfully. I followed https://docs.sylabs.io/guides/3.0/user-guide/installation.html#install-on-linux but basically package "singularity" is unavailable. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install -y singularity-container
E: Package 'singularity-container' has no installation candidate
```

Centos7:

```
sudo yum update -y && \
>     sudo yum install -y epel-release && \
>     sudo yum update -y && \
>     sudo yum install -y singularity-runtime singularity

No package singularity-runtime available.
No package singularity available.
```

Comment: It looks like the package you're trying to install is not available in either CentOS or Ubuntu. 
Try to install it from source instead, the instructions available here: https://github.com/sylabs/singularity/releases